# Convergence of partial sums and their inverses

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If a sequence $s_{k}$ of partial sums converges to a nonzero limit, and we assume that $s_{k} \neq 0$  for all $k$  $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{N}$, then also the sequence $\left \{ \frac{1}{s_{k}}  \right \}$ converges.

In my book, $s_{k}$ is defined as $\sum_{j = 1}^{k}\frac{a_{j}}{10^{j}}$
which is a decimal expansion.

I can't immediately see why this sequence converges - Maybe I'm just braindead today, but I can't think of any examples in my head that are making sense to me. Can anyone point me in the right direction about why this is true?

Comment: If you're not confused, then you're not learning anything new.  So it's good that you can't immediately see why the sequence converges.  It means you're learning something you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $\{a_n\}$ is any convergent sequence with a limit $a\neq 0$, then $\dfrac{1}{a_n}$ converges to $\dfrac{1}{a}$.

**Proof.** Let $\epsilon>0$. Then 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a}\right|=\left|\frac{a-a_{n}}{aa_n}\right|
$$
Since $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$, we can choose a positive integer $N_1$ such that if $n\ge N_1$, then $|a-a_n|\leq \dfrac{|a|}{2}$ for all $n\ge N_1$. This implies $a_n\ge\dfrac{|a|}{2}$ for all $n\ge N_1$. Now choose a positive integer $N_2$ such that $|a-a_n|\leq \dfrac{a^2}{2}\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N_2$. Let $N=\max(N_1, N_2)$. It follows that 
$$
\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a}\right|=\left|\frac{a-a_{n}}{aa_n}\right|=\frac{|a-a_n|}{|a||a_n|}\leq \frac{\frac{a^2}{2} \epsilon}{\frac{a^2}{2}}=\epsilon
$$
for each $n\ge N$. So $\dfrac{1}{a_n}\to\dfrac{1}{a}$ as desired.